# How are the following steps obtained in Cauchy Sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The exercise states that (V<sub>n</sub>) is a decreasing sequence converging at $0$. And let (u<sub>n</sub>) be as shown below

[image]

and then asks to prove that (u<sub>n</sub>) is a Cauchy sequence and thus convergent.

The definition of a cauchy sequence is given as:
[image]

The proof is shown below: [image]

The areas i'm a bit confused on are underlined in pink

**Firstly how would we write the sequence for u<sub>$n+m$</sub>?**

**In step 2: How did we get $n+m$ on top of sigma and how did we get $k=n+1$?**

**and lastly in step 3 why is the $(-1)$ to the power of $m-1$, shouldn't it be to the power of $n+1$ since $k=n+1$?**

Comment: The pink has made the highlighted parts unreadable.

Comment: I'm going to reupload the picture

Comment: They are now underlined in pink :)

Comment: Oh that makes sense, since the sequence now starts at k=n+1. Any idea why in step 3 it's to the power of m-1 though?

Comment: $u_{n+m}-u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}(-1)^kv_k-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kv_k.$ The terms from $k=0$ to $k=n$ cancel. This explains steps 1 and 2. As for step 3: $|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}(-1)^kv_k|=|(-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}(-1)^{k-n-1}v_k|=|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}(-1)^{k-n-1}v_k|=|v_{n+1}-\dots+(-1)^{m-1}v_{n+m}|.$

Comment: Thank you so so much!